# como puedo añadir una fila de una tabla con JS o Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

no se como añadir columnas a una tabla, cuando se pulsa un boton.

```js
var fila = 2;
var horas = "horas";
var horasFin;
var precioMax = "precioMax";
var precioMaxFin ;
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add").on("click",function(){
    horasFin = "horas" + fila;
    precioMaxFin = "precioMax" + fila;
    $clone=$("#ratios tbody tr:first").clone();
    $clone.find("input:eq(0)").each(function(){
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).attr("name",horasFin);
    });
    $clone.find("input:eq(1)").each(function(){
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).attr("name",precioMaxFin);
    });
    $("#ratios tbody").append($clone);
    fila++;
});
});
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="" action="Propietario" method="post">
  <table id="ratios" class="display dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Horas</th>
        <th>Precio máximo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  name="horas" value="" style="margin:1em auto;" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="precioMax" value="" style="margin:1em auto;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class="btn btnaction" id="add" type="button"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.añadir">Add</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btnaction btnamarillo" type="submit"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.añadir">Submit</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

El primer button, es el que necesito darle la funcionalidad, para que cuando se pulse, se cree otra fila como la de arriba. Pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.

Comment: No, se mas o menos como hacerlo, pero no se por donde empezar:S

Comment: Si, ya encontre lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias, edito la pregunta

Comment: Si, ya los añadi, pero no modifique la tabla en la pregunta. Lo que pasa que no me añade las filas :s y tampoco me da error en el desarrollador de chrome

Comment: Le has dado al ejecutar de tu pregunta?  está funcionando. aunque deberias añadir las filas debajo de las otras y no debajo de los botones

Comment: Si, en el ejemplo si que me lo hace, pero en mi proyecto no :S

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null Ese error me da

Comment: te lo da porque o no tienes ese id creado o porque el elemento no existe

Comment: Esta creado... Me da el error en el addeventlistener del boton... pero el boton esta creado y con el id :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo uses [jQuery](https://jquery.com), escribes menos y por ende desarrollas mas! ;))

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo. Es importante mencionar que podrás agregar columnas a tu código **html** sin tener que modificar el código **jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#add").on("click",function(){
  $clone=$("table tbody tr:first").clone();
  $clone.find("input").each(function(){
   $(this).val("");
  });
  $("table tbody").append($clone);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="" action="Propietario" method="post">
 <table id="ratios" class="display dataTable no-footer">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Horas</th>
    <th>Precio máximo</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="horas" value="" style="margin:1em;"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="precioMax" value="" style="margin:1em auto;"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td><button class="btn btnaction" id="add" type="button"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.añadir">Add</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btnaction btnamarillo" type="submit"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.añadir">Submit</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button></td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: No me funcion, porque si lo pongo, me dan fallos otras cosas de la pagina :S

Comment: Vale, ya lo consegui, muchas gracias, edito la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería funcionar así:

```
  function fila(){
    var row= document.createElement("TR");
        var cell1=document.createElement("TD");
                var text = document.createElement("INPUT");
                text.setAttribute("type", "text");
                text.setAttribute("name", "horas"+fila);
                text.setAttribute("style","margin:1em auto");
                cell1.appendChild(text);
       var cell2=document.createElement("TD");
                var text2 = document.createElement("INPUT");
                text2.setAttribute("type", "text");
                text2.setAttribute("name", "precioMax"+fila);
                text2.setAttribute("style","margin:1em auto");
                cell2.appendChild(text2);
                row.appendChild(cell1);
                row.appendChild(cell2);

                var table=document.getElementById("ratios");
                table.appendChild(row);


    }
```

El HTML sería algo así:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="" action="Propietario" method="post">
  <table id="ratios" class="display dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Horas</th>
        <th>Precio máximo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  name="horas" value="" style="margin:1em > 
         </td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="precioMax" value="" style="margin:1em auto;" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class="btn btnaction" id="add" type="button" onclick="fila()"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.añadir">Add</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btnaction btnamarillo" type="submit"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.añadir">Submit</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: El problema no lo tengo ahi, lo tengo en el boton parece.

Comment: @urrutias mira así a ver si te funciona, solo cambiando el html y poniendole al botón el evento onclick.

Comment: Pues me funciona, pero me saca la fila debajo de los botones :S